# How to make AutoParallaxBackground fit to the screen

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a android game with andengine. I use AutoParallaxBackground for repeating background. But my background image is not fit to the screen.How to solve the same

Here is my code

```
AutoParallaxBackground autoParallaxBackground=new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 10);
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-25.0f, new Sprite(0, 0, backgroundTextureRegion , engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()))); 
    gameScene.this.setBackground(autoParallaxBackground);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try to scale the sprite to fit the screen just before creating the ParallaxEntity, something like this:

```
AutoParallaxBackground autoParallaxBackground=new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 10);

Sprite mySprite = new Sprite(0, 0, backgroundTextureRegion , engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
mySprite.setScaleY(1.0f/( mySprite.getHeight() / CAMERA_HEIGHT));
mySprite.setScaleX(1.0f/( mySprite.getWidth() / CAMERA_WIDTH));

autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-25.0f, mySprite)); 
gameScene.this.setBackground(autoParallaxBackground);
```

Comment: i want to resize the autoparallaxBackground.. not the sprite